# How can I get notified when a certain Slack users posts in any public channel?

Tags: slack

I want to know when my CEO posts in a public Slack channel. How can I be notified when a specific user posts in any public slack channel I have access to?

Answer (score 5):

Got this answer from Slack support:

> May 8 2018, 4:29 PM PDT
>
> Hi Joshua,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch about this. Unfortunately, we don’t have a built-in way for you to handle getting notified when a certain user sends a message.
>
> However, this may be handled if you build a Slack app to monitor the channel and notify you as needed. If you're interested, then you can get started here:
>
> https://api.slack.com/slack-apps
>   That site will walk you through the various integration points we have available, along with details about the requirements for submitting your app for inclusion in the directory.
>
> I'll also mention this as a feature request to the team and hopefully they'll take this into consideration, but I can't make any guarantees. Thanks for your understanding here.

So Slack doesn't support it, thinking there may be a Slack bot I can create.

Answer (score 4):

Got this answer from Zapier support.

> Hi Joshua,
>
> Happy to help! I'd set up a Zap like follows:
>
> 1. Trigger (Slack): New Public Message Posted Anywhere
> 2. Filter: Only continue if user_id (or name) is your CEO's.
> 3. Action: Whatever you want your action to be.
>
> Bear in mind this requires a multi-step Zap, which is a Premium feature, but it will definitely let you get the results you're after! (In fact, I might steal this workflow for myself...)
>
> Let me know if there's anything I can clarify further for you—super happy to help. :)

Comment: Sidenote: That is such a great customer support message. That person deserves a raise or promotion or both!